# Is it possible to refresh a $_SESSION[] global variable for sure?

Tags: php, javascript

i have a PHP application that uses $_SESSION global to manage data inside the app. However i have a little problem when trying to update the values of $_SESSION, this is what i have done so far:

1. do stuff
2. unset($_SESSION['var'])
3. do stuff
4. $_SESSION['var']=newValue();

I call the php using `$.post()` like this:

```
$('#id').click(function(){
    $.post("page.php", function(data){
        //do stuff
        window.location = "goto.php";
    })
})
```

`goto.php` grabs the content from $_SESSION['var'] and construct a new html.

But, when the webpage goes to `goto.php` it loads the html that was created using the last version of `$_SESSION['var']`. Note that if i refresh the webpage, then it load the new content created with the new `$_SESSION['var']`.

Also this is not a regular behavior, sometimes it loads right without the page reload.

What i'm i doing so fundamentally wrong in here?

Comment: Have you checked that it is loading the latest page by clearing your cache?

Comment: Yes only by doing a page refresh it gets the right content. @SableFoste

Comment: I am not an expert, but apparently the jQuery $.post does update your $_SESSION variable, but because it is an AJAX request, the current page displayed doesn't change until refreshed.  Is your original page (that you call the $.post) goto.php, or page.php, or another page altogether?

Comment: @SableFoste the page from which the $.post is called it's actually a different page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a cache issue. You can send certain headers to the browser to force it not to cache the page, and thus ensure a reload everytime.

You can do this in PHP using:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
```

Source: [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

Comment: hm, i asume this answer means that nothing is cached, for example images. Is there no half way to define what to cache and what not to cache?

Comment: It's only for that specific page. Do you have images or anything of that sort on this page?